# Switch Statement in Javascript isn't switching

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

What is wrong with this switch statement? The value I would be selecting this from a select menu with the options/values being 1 or 2. The input field keeps displaying just "1" when it should be "$1500"

```
$('[name="costfield"]').change(function(){
    var cost = this.value;
    switch(cost){
        case 1:
            cost = "$1500";
            break;
        case 2:
            cost = "$2500";
            break;

    }
    $('#exampleInputEstimate1').val(cost);
});
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your `cost` variable to check its value?

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the value from the input, you get strings, i.e. '1' or '2'.
Therefore you have to parse it as an integer or a float:

Replace:

```
var cost = this.value;
```

with:

```
var cost = parseInt(this.value, 10);
```

The other solution would be to enumerate strings in the switch/case, as it was already pointed:

```
switch(cost){
    case '1':
        cost = "$1500";
        break;
    case '2':
        cost = "$2500";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

By the way take the habit to write a default case in switch statements

Answer (score 0):

The `switch` statement use *strict comparison* according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Description).

For appropriate use I suggest using strings in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use strings in the case statement - https://jsfiddle.net/3ujg7kr8/

```
$('[name="costfield"]').change(function(){
    var cost = this.value;

    switch(cost){
        case '1':
            cost = "$1500";
            break;
        case '2':
            cost = "$2500";
            break;

    }

    $('#exampleInputEstimate1').val(cost);
});
```